# how to change arguments of caller function by Function.prototype.apply()?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, apply

```
function foo1(a,b){
   console.log(arguments); //["oldValue","oldValue"]

   var newArguments = foo2.apply(this,arguments);
   for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
      arguments[i] = newArguments[i];   
}
   console.log(arguments); //["newValue","newValue"]
}

function foo2(){
   arguments[0] = "newValue";
   arguments[1] = "newValue";
   console.log(arguments); //["newValue","newValue"]
   return arguments;
}

foo1("oldValue","oldValue");
```

I'd like to change foo1 arguments values by outer function foo2. I did it by returning array with new arguments in foo2 and replacing foo1 arguments with returned array in foo1. Is there any other - more elegant - way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you receive the `arguments` directly?

```
function foo1() {
  console.log('foo1', arguments); // foo1 { '0': 'oldValue', '1': 'oldValue' }

  arguments = foo2.apply(this, arguments); 

  console.log('foo1', arguments); // foo1 { '0': 'newValue', '1': 'newValue' }

}

function foo2() {
  arguments[0] = 'newValue';
  arguments[1] = 'newValue';
  console.log('foo2', arguments); // foo2 { '0': 'newValue', '1': 'newValue' }
  return arguments;
}

foo1('oldValue', 'oldValue');
```

---

**Update 1**

Since you want to change `a`, `b` also, I would try calling `foo1` "again" like below:

```
function foo1(a, b) {
  console.log('foo1', arguments);

  if (a === 'oldValue') // Detect if `arguments` has been changed or not. 
                        // (You can also use a variable to record the change if you prefer.)
    // If not, change the arguments and call `foo1` using the new arguments
    return foo1.apply(this, foo2.apply(this, arguments));

  console.log('foo1 (after changed)', arguments , a, b);
  // Do something you want to do originally in `foo1`
}
```

I suppose that you can make a new function instead of change the arguments inside the `foo1`, since it seems a little tricky to me?

Comment: if I receive arguments directly but have some properties set like this foo1(a,b), then a and b remain unchanged if I refer to them (while arguments[0], arguments[1] returns new values).

Answer (score 0):

https://jsbin.com/jibodu/1/edit?js,console

If you're returning the two new arguments from `foo2` just set the arguments to that return value:

```
arguments = foo2();
```

full code:

```
function foo1(a,b){
   console.log(arguments); //["oldValue","oldValue"]
    arguments = foo2();
   var newArguments = foo2.apply(this,arguments);
   for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
      arguments[i] = newArguments[i];   
}
   console.log(arguments); //["newValue","newValue"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I found resolution. I've just changed first parameter in apply() to "arguments". Now it refers to arguments of caller function and by 'this' I can directly change its values. nonetheless thanks for support!

```
function foo1(a, b) {
   foo2.apply(arguments,arguments);
   console.log(arguments);  //["newValue","newValue"]
   console.log(a); //"newValue"
}
function foo2() {
   this[0] = "newValue";
   this[1] = "newValue";
};
foo1("oldValue","oldValue");
```